# Django - having different MEDIA_ROOT for different users

Tags: django, django-forms, image-uploading, django-models

I am using Django 1.5 and I want users to be able to upload photos. I want the photos to be stored in a different location depending on what the users ID is. So for example, if a user uploads a file and the users ID is 1 (the ID / unique primary key given to each user when a user object is created from the Django generic User model), then I want the image to be saved in the directory

```
myPorjectFolder/myApp/static/site_media/images/1(the users ID)/uploadedPhotos
```

This is how I think I am supposed to do it. In settings.py, add this line:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/userName/myProject/myApp/site_media/static/images/'
```

and then in the models.py, create the model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserImages(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToManyField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=currentUsersID/uploadedPhotos) #I know this won't work.. how would I make it work?
```

Am I right? Or is it done a totally different way than what I am thinking?

Edit: my forms.py is this:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the id of the user, you can create a function to upload the image like so:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
  return os.path.join('%s/uploadedPhotos' % instance.user_id, filename)
```

Then in  your model's ImageField you'll do

```
class UserImages(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKeyField(User)
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

Also note that I used a ForeignKeyField for the user property. There is no OneToManyField, just ForeignKey, OneToOne and ManyToMany.

Edit:

For your form usage, you could do:

```
form = UploadImageForm(request.POST)
form.instance.user = request.user
user_image = form.save()
```

But you'd need to modify your forms.py to the following:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = UserImages
    fields = ['photo']
```

Comment: hm oh okay, but when you do "upload_to=get_file_path", doesn't get_file_path() take two parameters? What is instance and filename and how does the get_file_path() function know what they are even when it is not supplied by upload_to=get_file_path?

Comment: ```instance``` is the instance of the UserImages class that's being saved, and filename is the name of the file that's being saved to the photo property.

Comment: hm okay I just added my forms.py to my post. So in my view, if I do "user = request.user" and then "UserImages.objects.create( user=user, photo=form.cleaned_data['image']" then it will automatically add the image to usersID/uploadedPhotos/filename ?

Comment: See my edit for a better way to handle that using a ModelForm rather than just a Form. Note, that it doesn't show the ```is_valid``` check. I just wanted to show the basics of saving a ModelForm.

Comment: hm okay thanks. I'll mark it as answered, but just a few more questions to clarify 3 things. 
--1-- Instead of doing "form.instance.user = request.user" I could have achieved the same thing with "user = request.user", right? 
--2-- what exactly does the "user_image = form.save()" line do?
and --3-- Is the "fields = ['photo']" line needed? According to the Django docs, it says " This attribute (fields), if given, should be a list of field names to include in the form".. so even if I don't include the "fields = ['photos']" line, the code will still do the same thing right?

Comment: 1) Yes you could have. 2) Read the docs for the best answer, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method 3) Yes and no. The form would expect you to have a user specified on the form. If you used ```{{form.as_p}}``` in the template it would render a form input for the user. By only specifying the photo field, it wouldn't render that field.